How to check if Parameter is binded in C# blazor?
I've written a component which has 30 or so parameters and would like to automatically setup this component when values are binded.
This works fine when a value is set, however some of the values are nullable and can be null. When given a value of 'null' the component cannot check if it's set, so I'm wondering:
Is it possible to check in the component if a variable is binded? If so, how?
if(DemoValue.isBinded) {}


How about if(DemoValue != null) {}?

Like I said, sometimes the value which is binded is null, so then this will not work

There is a way which is to set the bindings manually, but it's labour intensive - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-8.0#implement-setparametersasync-manually

The standard pattern for using SetParametersAsync is:
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // You should always do this first
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        // do you stuff

        // pass an empty set of parameters to base as you've already set them
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

So your version can be updated to this.
    private List<string> bindedParameters = new();
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            bindedParameters.Add(parameter.Name);
        }

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }


But why do I need to set them manually? I only need the names and I can passthrough the list to the base then?

You should always set the parameters immediately (I believe it's a Blazor team recommendation).  So if you override SetParametersAsync that's the first thing you do.  You may do a lot of work in SetParametersAsync, so the values may become stale before you make the base call.  It's probably one of the reasons for having ParameterView.Empty.

Thanks to the comment of @MrC aka Shaun Curtis, I could make the following function:
private List<string> bindedParameters = new();
public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        bindedParameters.Add(parameter.Name);
    }
    return base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
}

Anywhere else in the code the variable can be checked like so:
if (bindedParameters.Contains(nameof(ParamterToCheck))) Console.WriteLine("This parameter is binded");
else Console.WriteLine("This parameter is not binded");


See my answer about how to refactor your SetParametersAsync.
